# Refer to the class inside of a JPanel action listner

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, this

I'm trying to refer to my class in a method within a action listener so I can pass it though the method. My code looks a little something like this:

My MainPanel Class:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel{    

private JButton submitButton;
JTextArea consoleOutput;

public MainPanel(){

    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    setLayout(null);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Font f1 = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14);

    submitButton = new JButton("Get Cards");
    submitButton.setBounds(35, 285, 107, 49);
    submitButton.setFont(f1);

    consoleOutput = new JTextArea();
    consoleOutput.setBounds(199, 122, 375 , 210);
    consoleOutput.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 4, 0, 0)));
    consoleOutput.setEditable(false);
    consoleOutput.setFont(f1);

    submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String username;
            String password;
            Cards cards = new Cards();
            cards.openTabs(username, password, this); //THIS IS THE METHOD IM TRYING TO PASS THE CLASS INTO
            }

        });
        add(submitButton);
        add(consoleOutput);
    }   
}
```

My Cards Class:

```
public class Cards{

    public void openTabs(String username, String password, MainPanel panel){
        panel.consoleOutput.setText(username + ", " + password);
    }
```

In eclipse it underlines the method in my MainPanel and this is the problem or error is has:

```
The method openTabs(String, String, MainPanel) in the type Cards is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, new ActionListener(){})
```

What should I do? What should I pass in instead of this because it seems not not be working. I'm lost and have no idea what to do, Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Side note on code quality: obviously you are just learning to program in Java, nonetheless it might be good for you too also learn how to write not only working code, but "good" code. Thus I recommend you to check out "Clean code" by Robert Martin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using **this** within an anonymous **inner** class. In other words: this `this` has not the usual meaning of `this` - it doesn't refer the "outer" MainPanel object, but the inner ActionListener object!

You have to use `MainPanel.this` instead!

Comment: You are welcome; and don't forget to "accept" my answer when that action becomes available to you ;-)